# How to understand encryption method and decrypt?

Tags: rot13

I have a word and i guess its encrypted with rot18. (Im not sure which encrypting method used). Im trying to decrypt this word with online decrypters but i couldnt get a string. after decryption, i got another word like encrypted with rot18 again.

by the way i dont know my word's encryption key to decrypt it directly.

my question is which encrypting method used? and how can i decrypt it to a string?

```
this is my key to decode --> Iuhzhuuhidez98735
result after decoding process --> 5h4m4hh4501m98735
```

Comment: Hint: Caesar cipher is rot3

Comment: @kelalaka do you know how can i decrypt this code? i tried online decrypters but i wrote the results on my question :S

Comment: It is your task. You should look your alphabet size

Comment: @kelalaka i added 0123456789 to alphabet but result is same

Comment: Do you write some code? If so, show it here, otherwise, this is going to be closed...

Comment: @kelalaka im using online decrypters. i didnt write a code